# Json ARM file to Bicep conversion : dynamic variable conversion error : replace with correct path to [variables('abc')]

Tags: json, azure-bicep

`I'm trying to convert a json file to bicep. There is one segment which expecting string URL after module. The variable TemplateURL is the variable which represents the URL required. But it's not accepted.

converted bicep ::

```
param _artifactsLocation string = deployment().properties.templateLink.uri
param _artifactsLocationSecurityToken string = ''
**var TemplateURL = '${_artifactsLocation}/nested/join-       cluster.bicep${_artifactsLocationSecurityToken}'**
**module abc '?' /*TODO: replace with correct path to [variables('TemplateURL')]*/ = **{
  name: 'abc'
  params: {
  }
```

}

Error ::
replace with correct path to [variables('TemplateURL')]

I tried to replace '?' with 'TemplateURL' got another error.
**module joincluster 'TemplateURL'
Error::
An error occurred reading file. Could not find file '.\path'\TemplateURL

it looks like it's taking string TemplateURL as url.
how to fix it?
`

Comment: you can't reference a remote module unless it is hosterd in container registry: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/private-module-registry?tabs=azure-powershell

Comment: you could always have the module locally ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for pointing towards the proper direction, @Thomas.

*To share modules in bicep,*

> create a [template spec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/template-specs), [public registry](https://github.com/Azure/bicep-registry-modules), or [private registry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/private-module-registry). Template specs and modules in the registry are only available to users with the correct permissions.

Refer [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/modules) for Bicep modules.

e.g., If you are deploying to a private registry, you can use existing registries or create a new one, and then publish all modules to the registry using the relevant commands with `PowerShell or CLI`. Obtain a login server name for the registry as shown.

```
Get-AzContainerRegistry -ResourceGroupName "xxxx" -Name "xxxx"
```

[image]

Then, use the following command to deploy into the repository, which prompts for a target location as well as the path of the file in which it is placed.

```
Publish-AzBicepModule
```

[image]

*As I referenced above, you can proceed with the required steps to deploy modules into registries or template specs.*

Refer this [github](https://github.com/Azure/bicep/discussions/3896) issue for the relevant information.

Comment: it's not able to decode the string url from given variable TemplateURL. It's showing like syntax error in visual studio code itself.

Comment: Can you paste here the full error message? @Talang_madave